# The projection of density $1$ point on a rectifiable set

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I posted this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602464/the-projection-of-density-1-point-on-a-rectifiable-set) on MSE but I received no reply. So I repost this here for better luck. Thank you!

Let $\Gamma\subset \mathbb R^N$ be $\mathcal H^{N-1}$-[rectifiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifiable_set). Then we know that $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ a.e. $x\in \Gamma$ has density $1$. In particular, let $\nu(x)\in \mathcal S^{N-1}$ be the vector at $x\in \Gamma$ normal to $\Gamma$, and $Q(x,r)$ be a cube centered at $x$ with side length $r$ and two faces normal to $\nu(x)$, we have
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\mathcal H^{N-1}(Q(x,r)\cap \Gamma)}{r^{N-1}}=1
$$
for $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ a.e. $x\in\Gamma$.

> My question: Fix $x\in \Gamma$ satisfies above. Let $T_x$ denote the hyperplane normal to $\nu(x)$ and passing through $x$. Then, do we have
>   $$
> \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\mathcal H^{N-1}(\mathbb P_x[Q(x,r)\cap \Gamma])}{r^{N-1}}=1?
> $$

Where $\mathbb P_x$ is the projection operator which projects $x\in \Gamma$ onto the hyperplane $T_x$. For example, if $T_x = \{x_N=0\}$, then $\mathbb P_x(x)=(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_{N-1},0)$ where $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_N)$.

PS: I know for instance that 
$$
\mathcal H^{N-1}\lfloor\left(\frac{\Gamma-x}{r}\right)\to \mathcal H^{N-1}\lfloor \mathbb P_x
$$
weakly as $r\to 0$. I think I may conclude from this statement but still...feel there is still a gap...

Any help is really welcome! Thx!

Comment: Question: what is **the** tangent vector $\nu(x)$? There should be an hyperplane tangent to $x \in \Gamma$, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi The tangent vector $\nu(x)$ is the vector normal to $\Gamma$ at $x$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So it's the *normal* vector to the tangent hyperplane of $x$, **not** the tangent vector. Which makes $T_x$ the tangent hyperplane.

Comment: Sure sure. You are right.  $T_x$ should be the tangent hyperplane of $\Gamma$, and $\nu(x)$ is a vector normal to $\Gamma$

Comment: As a rectifiable set, $\Gamma$ can be covered up to a negligible set by countably many $C^1$ submanifolds $M_k$ of the same dimension. The statement should be correct for each $M_k$ separately. I think it then follows rather quickly for a density point of $\Gamma \cap M_k \setminus \bigcup_{i \neq k} M_i$ for any $k$. This should imply your statement.

Comment: Although this argument shows that your statement is true for almost every point $x$, you cannot fix a point x as you say and only assume that the density and a weak tangent plane at $x$ exists. To see this consider the $1$-rectifiable set $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ obtained as the union over all integers $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ of the vertical segments $\{\frac{1}{n}\} \times [0,\frac{1}{|n|(|n|+1)}]$. Then the horizontal axis is a weak tangent plane at $(0,0)$ (with the right density) but the projection of $\Gamma$ onto the horizontal axis has measure zero.

Comment: @rozu: Thank you! So what I can have is that for this $\Gamma$, a.e. $x\in\Gamma$ has density 1 in normal sense and also in the sense as I defined in my post right?

Comment: @tankonetoone: Yes I'm quite certain about that, following the sketch of a proof above (and you assume that $\Gamma$ has locally finite $\mathcal H^{N-1}$-measure).